# Loop through SqlLite records. How is that efficient, in my case?

Tags: java, android

I have one question.

I have an application which retreives images from my web server. My activity shows one image and two buttons (previous and next).

I want to upgrade my app, and integrate "favourites" option. So if user likes particular image, url string (not image) is saved in sqlite database.

Question:

I will put ImageView and act like a button. That ImageView will show a hearth or something so it will indicate that user can tap, to save url to sqlite database. I want that ImageView be different if that url string already exists in database. That means that with every image I will need to loop through all urls in database. How is that efficient? Can I do that, or I will afect device performance?

So again if somebody didn't understood.

1. Show activity where image is shown
2. Click on button (next , previous )
3. Check through all urls (or until match is detected) in database in case it matches
4. If there is a match, change ImageView ( like, from yellow star, to red star. That means , image is already "favourited")

Will this affect android performance? (

I hope you understand what I meant.

Thank you for help.

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to query the DB if the urls is already in there than iterating over all urls in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is regarding the performance of SQLite SELECT statements.

You say "Check through all urls (or until match is detected) in database in case it matches".

I think you're implying a loop, but really you just want to build your SELECT statement properly so SQL does the heavy lifting. Selecting a single row from the DB shouldn't be slow. Selecting ALL the rows, then looping in java might be.

You want to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `url`="http://www.someurl.com/image.jpg"
```

Which would return one result that's an exact match. no loops, just if you have a result, the image is saved, and if nothing is returned, the image is not saved.

Unless you have millions of entries, I imagine the above technique will perform quite well.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences for this purpose it is much better for performance here [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html) has some good tutorial for this , and [android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) provide one too , it is much easier to detect duplicates too

Comment: Hmm, what if user saves 500, or 1000 urls?

Comment: It seemed for me that your case is a key/value pair storage, which I prefer for a SharedPreference both will take a large data storage if grown up too much but I believe that the implementation of SharedPreferences make searching and editing a lot easier

Comment: Sqlite is meant for more robust relational database however it is left for you to decide